Please tell me how to solve this problem? Can't install chrome [Solved]
Thank you everyone,
I found the solution to the problem and shared it.
Enter the following command.
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
sudo rm opera-archive.list
wget -c https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

==========================================================
Please tell me how to solve this problem? Can't install chrome
sudo apt install chrome
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/opera-browser.gpg != 

E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/opera-browser.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/opera.gpg

E: The list of sources could not be read.

and
apt-get upgrade
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/opera-browser.gpg != 
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/opera-browser.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/opera.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?


The errors are regarding opera. Which browser are you installing? Your question is about chrome.

Both are installed, but chrome suddenly disappears. I want to install it again, but it doesn't work.

This question is similar to: How to solve "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source..." for a deb repository?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
